# Visual Studio 2015 read commented app. setting value from web config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, webforms, .net-4.0, web-config

Visual Studio 2015 read commented app. setting value from web config.

```
<!--<add key="test" value="1"/>-->
<add key="test" value="2"/>
```

I get `1` from my code.
Even if I remove `<!--<add key="test" value="1"/>-->`, I still get `1`.
I don't have `clean solution` option, only `build solution` and `rebuild solution`
I rebuild solution, same issue.
I close visual studio then open again, same issue.

The problem go away after a while, I cannot pinpoint what trigger this behavior.

Comment: close the solution and go to project folder and delete the bin and obj folder,
sometime you may have some errors, in your code and you might be running last successful build, normally VS is prompting before running the code if any error in your code if you haven't disabled it, check if disabled -> Tools -> Option -> Project and Solution -> change the selected option to Prompt to launch in the On-Run,when build or deployment error occur:

Comment: @DilanWickramarathna my project don't have your typical VS 2015 bin folder and obj folder.

Comment: is it something like WebSite project that you opened like File -> Open -> WebSite ?

Comment: @DilanWickramarathna No, it have VS2010 solution file, I open it with VS2015.

Comment: Is it running with Local IIS? if yes you have to cleat asp.net temporary files, clean the folder located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because I set my project to use custom server point to http://localhost/myWebsite and it's reading value from there.